# "Unable to find a matching set of capabilities" with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I know this question has been asked *multiple* times but hear me out.

Please find the versions I am using below:

- Python 3.7.9
- Mozilla Firefox 81.0
- Selenium 3.141.0
- Geckodriver 0.27.0
- Architecture: x86-64
- Kernel: Linux 5.8.11-1-MANJARO

According to the [docs](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html), the required versions for Geckodriver 0.27.0 are:

- Selenium >= 3.11
- Firefox >= 60

I also made sure I installed 64-bit versions of Python, Selenium, and Firefox. It seems to me that I have all the matching capabilities.

However, if I run the following code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

...I still get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/shoaib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/shoaib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/shoaib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/shoaib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/shoaib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

I'll tell you what I have tried:

- Using the `--headless` option:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

- Using the `executable_path` path:

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
```

- Using `FirefoxBinary`:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/lib/firefox/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

which gives me a different error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/shoaib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/shoaib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/shoaib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/shoaib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/shoaib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

- Setting `marionette` to `False`:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
caps['marionette'] = False
driver=webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
```

which yet again gives me a different error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/shoaib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 191, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "/home/shoaib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/shoaib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 73, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/shoaib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 104, in _wait_until_connectable
    "The browser appears to have exited "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

I am truly stuck.

Thank you for your timely help!

Comment: Hi if you are having problems with your capabilities. I'd suggest pip installing webdriver-manager in command prompt and just using driver = webdriver.Firefox(GeckoDriverManager().install()). Then import from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager. It should handle all the matching capabilities for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I used the webdriver-manager but it did not help. It installed Geckodriver 0.27.0 and I end up getting the same error :(